# Display selected results only from the database table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to display only a selected result on my php page.

This is my php code:

```
$bookdetsql = "
SELECT b.bookISBN
     , b.bookTitle
     , b.bookYear
     , b.catID
     , b.pubID
     , p.pubName
     , p.location
     , c.catDesc
     , b.bookPrice 
  FROM nbc_book b
  LEFT 
  JOIN nbc_category c 
    ON b.catID = c.catID 
  LEFT 
  JOIN nbc_publisher p 
    ON b.pubID = p.pubID
";


$bookdetrs = mysqli_query($conn, $bookdetsql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$bookdetnum = mysqli_num_rows($bookdetrs);

if($bookdetnum >= 1 ){
echo "<div style='margin: 0 0 10px 0; font-weight: bold;'>$bookdetnum record(s) found!</div>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bookdetrs)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['bookTitle']."</a></center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['bookYear']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['catDesc']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['bookPrice']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['pubName']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['location']."</center></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

} else {
   echo "<b>Books not found!</b>";
}
```

Actually this code above is displaying the whole list of records actually. I only want it to display selected record which i clicked on my first php page.

Comment: @Strawberry i have added the column identifiers

Comment: Consider the following: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/draxo Here you can see that while an entire data set is returned, only a subset of it need ever be displayed. (Actually, this example doesn't work quite as one would expect - but it could)

Comment: this is using javascript.. I dont want to use javascript.

Comment: Yes - but what's wrong with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you get the values frmo the first page? GET or POST?

when you have the value(s), you can add an where clause to your SELECT Statement

```
$bookdetsql = "SELECT bookISBN, bookTitle, bookYear, nbc_book.catID, nbc_book.pubID, pubName,  location, catDesc, bookPrice 
                 FROM nbc_book 
            LEFT JOIN nbc_category ON nbc_book.catID = nbc_category.catID 
            LEFT JOIN nbc_publisher ON nbc_book.pubID = nbc_publisher.pubID
                WHERE bookISBN = '" . $_GET["bookISBN"] . "'";
```

Comment: well i am not using both.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602687/display-data-from-another-php-site/27602904#27602904) this is what i did on my first page.

Comment: is 'bookid' an integer or a string (varchar)?

Comment: actually... I am not using bookid. I am using the bookISBN as the primary key. Well now my first php page i have tabulated the whole date, now i want to let the user to click on the book on the first php page and then open  the second php page which shows the selected book record

Comment: ok.. then you have to use '' -> Updated... did you see the ISBN number in your URL? (bookdetails.php?bookISBN=13-12-56456-4156)

Comment: ok.. with echo $bookdetsql; (after you define your selectStatement) what did you get?

Comment: This is what i get 

"SELECT bookISBN, bookTitle, bookYear, nbc_book.catID, nbc_book.pubID, pubName, location, catDesc, bookPrice FROM nbc_book LEFT JOIN nbc_category ON nbc_book.catID = nbc_category.catID LEFT JOIN nbc_publisher ON nbc_book.pubID = nbc_publisher.pubID WHERE bookISBN = 5886313197

Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli"
Warning: mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli"

Comment: ok.. in this case, you have to add '' arround your ISBN number. Like this '" . $_GET["bookISBN"] . "'". does this work?

Answer (score 1):

```
Pleas Replace left join to join because left join is fetch matching and unmatch both record but when you use simple join it is work on inner join and fetch only match record according to your requirement   


$bookdetsql = "SELECT bookISBN, bookTitle, bookYear, nbc_book.catID, nbc_book.pubID, pubName,  location, catDesc, bookPrice FROM nbc_book JOIN nbc_category ON nbc_book.catID = nbc_category.catID JOIN nbc_publisher ON nbc_book.pubID = nbc_publisher.pubID";

$bookdetrs = mysqli_query($conn, $bookdetsql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$bookdetnum = mysqli_num_rows($bookdetrs);

if($bookdetnum >= 1 ){
echo "<div style='margin: 0 0 10px 0; font-weight: bold;'>$bookdetnum record(s) found!</div>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bookdetrs)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['bookTitle']."</a></center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['bookYear']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['catDesc']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['bookPrice']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['pubName']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['location']."</center></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

} else {
   echo "<b>Books not found!</b>";
}
```