# Cannot display search results in a new PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having trouble in displaying my search results onto another php page.

Below is my php code for my second php page:

```
if (isset($_GET['bookTitle'])) {
    $bookTitle = $_GET['bookTitle'];
    $sqlSearch = "SELECT bookISBN, bookTitle, bookYear, nbc_book.catID, nbc_book.pubID, pubName,  location, catDesc, bookPrice FROM nbc_book
    LEFT JOIN nbc_category ON nbc_book.catID = nbc_category.catID
    LEFT JOIN nbc_publisher ON nbc_book.pubID = nbc_publisher.pubID LIKE CONCAT('%', bookTitle, '%') 
    WHERE bookTitle = " . $_GET['booktitle'] ;
    echo "string";
    $resultSearch = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlSearch) or die (mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSearch)){
        $category = $row['catDesc'];
        $bookTitle = $row['bookTitle'];
        $publisherName = $row['pubName'];
        $bookYear = $row['bookYear'];
        $bookPrice = $row['bookPrice'];
        echo "Result found!";
    }
}else{

    echo "Result not found!";
}

mysqli_free_result($resultSearch);
mysqli_close($conn);
```

This is the error i am getting:

```
Result not found!
Notice: Undefined variable: querySearch in /

Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /
```

Can anyone help me to solve my problem. I would be glad if someone can help me solve this problem.

Comment: where is the code where "**querySearch**" is in?

Comment: and booktitle is lowercase in WHERE clause

Comment: @MarkoC actually I am getting the variable from the my first php page which i set booktitle as lower case

Comment: @donald123 sorry the querySearch is the resultSearch

Comment: maybe it's my lack of knowledge, but maybe that "LIKE CONCAT('%', bookTitle, '%')" is misplaced. Didn't you mean to write: "WHERE bookTitle like '%$bookTitle%'" ? (apart from the fact that using unprocessed parameters is insecure. See: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display selected results only from the database table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604245/display-selected-results-only-from-the-database-table)

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself...

Comment: If you formatted your queries properly, and adhered to previous advice, you'd find this kind of thing a lot easier.

Comment: @Strawberry ok thanks I will try to follow the previous advice

Comment: @Strawberry at the same time why I am getting the error messages as shown above?

Comment: Once you've formatted your query correctly, see if you can tell me!

Comment: @RaajLokanathan, have you tried your query in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin no i didnt..

Comment: @RaajLokanathan, then do it; have you access to phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin yes i have access.. i just test it, it shows there is an syntax error on my sql statement..

Comment: Also, take a look at prepared statements (in PHP's mysql_ API) - although it can be better to do this AFTER debugging the query!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> WHERE bookTitle = " . $_GET['booktitle'] ;

you've missed to wrap value with quotes `'`:

```
 WHERE bookTitle = '" . $_GET['booktitle'] . "' " ;
```

### Update

> why I am getting the error messages as shown above?

**Because you try to close sql connection apart from opening it!**

I've moved `mysqli_free_result($resultSearch);` and `mysqli_close($conn);` inside brasked:

```
if (isset($_GET['bookTitle'])) {
  $bookTitle = $_GET['bookTitle'];
  $sqlSearch = "SELECT bookISBN, bookTitle, bookYear, nbc_book.catID, nbc_book.pubID, pubName,  location, catDesc, bookPrice FROM nbc_book
LEFT JOIN nbc_category ON nbc_book.catID = nbc_category.catID
LEFT JOIN nbc_publisher ON nbc_book.pubID = nbc_publisher.pubID LIKE CONCAT('%', bookTitle, '%') 
WHERE bookTitle = " . $_GET['booktitle'] ;
  echo "string";
  $resultSearch = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlSearch) or die (mysql_error());

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSearch)){
    $category = $row['catDesc'];
    $bookTitle = $row['bookTitle'];
    $publisherName = $row['pubName'];
    $bookYear = $row['bookYear'];
    $bookPrice = $row['bookPrice'];
    echo "Result found!";

  mysqli_free_result($resultSearch);
  mysqli_close($conn);
   }
}else{ 
   echo "Result not found!";
}
```

Seems the `$_GET['booktitle']` is not provided, but in your code you try to free result and close nothing!

Comment: but that doesnt answer my question.. I am getting an error message actually @igor

Comment: I have solved the error message, but now my sql query is giving some problem.

Comment: @RaajLokanathan, try to test it first in phpMyAdmin and then apply in php.